# What form of logic is necessary for practical philosophy?

Tags: logic

Logic is broad and concerns different fields, so to be more specific with the purpose of logic what is the most important form of which required for practical philosophy?

Comment: As mentioned before, your questions do not show the problem at (your) hand. Please be a little more cooperative. You've asked "what is the best logic for x/y/z philosophy", and in neither question do you provide any information.

Comment: As iphigenie points out, this question is sorely lacking context and is just too broad and too subjective to be reasonably answered. Please try to narrow your question to a specific concern...

Answer (score 1):

There are two useful branches of logic to apply in philosophy and science.  Inductive logic and Deductive logic.  Deductive logic begins with a set of premises, from which conclusions are formed.  Inductive logic begins with an examination of specific results, from which hypotheses are made about general results.

Both branches of logic are useful in philosophy.  If one starts with some basic assumptions, and wants to deduce consequences of such assumptions, deductive reasoning is best.  If one wants to determine the underlying principles behind why people act the way they do, or why things are the way they are, then inductive reasoning, followed by experimentation is suited.  Often inductive logic is useful in reflection of personal experiences, which is important in practical philosophy.